# How can I make hibernate not override ID in object to be saved, and rather use its ID?

Tags: mysql, spring, hibernate, spring-boot, jpa

I'm trying to save a Foo object with ID=20. In my MySQL db the last row has Foo with ID=5. When I use the `save` function in the JpaRepository, it saves the object, but instead of using the ID I wanted it to have (20), it uses 6.

```
@Entity
@Data
@ToString
@NoArgsConstructor
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
public class Foo implements Serializable {

    @Id
    private long id;
```

I have tried with `@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)`, but that doesn't work either. Is there a way to configure Hibernate not take the next sequential ID, but use what is stored in the object?

Comment: Please provide the table definition (DDL).

Comment: CREATE TABLE `foo` (
  `id` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1; basically this

Comment: Are you sure that the id do not generated by database? Maybe some trigger do this. The `GenerationType.IDENTITY` strategy should be used only in this case.